Terraform aws_lambda_layer_version creates new version for every run
I have a terraform config to create a lambda layer in AWS,
variable "package_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of the lambda layer"
  default     = "google-cloud-bigquery"
}


resource "null_resource" "install_package" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = path.module
    command     = "chmod +x build_lambda_layer_package.sh; ./build_lambda_layer_package.sh ${var.package_name}"
  }
  triggers = {
    id = var.package_name
    always_update = timestamp()
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/${var.package_name}"
  output_path = "${path.module}/${var.package_name}.zip"
  depends_on  = [null_resource.install_package]
}


# AWS Lambda Layer
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "layer_google_cloud_bigquery" {
  filename                 = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path
  source_code_hash         = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256
  layer_name               = var.package_name
  compatible_runtimes      = var.layer_compatible_runtimes
  compatible_architectures = var.layer_compatible_architectures
  depends_on               = [data.archive_file.lambda_zip]

}

build_lambda_layer_package.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the package name is provided as argument
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <package_name>"
  exit 1
fi

# Package name provided as argument
PACKAGE_NAME="$1"

# Define the target directory for your AWS Lambda layer Python packages
TARGET_DIR="${PACKAGE_NAME}/python"

# Create the directory structure
mkdir -p $TARGET_DIR

# Install the package into the target directory
pip3 install $PACKAGE_NAME -t $TARGET_DIR

When I execute terraform apply for the first time, it creates a version. But when I apply again it destroys the old version and creates a new version again, even though the source_code_hash has not changed.
I want to avoid creating a new version if a layer with the identical source_code_hash already exists.
It's worth noting that, if I remove the null_resource block and create the google-cloud-bigquery.zip zip file manually then aws_lambda_layer_version does not create a new version. I can't seem to understand the relation between "null_resource" "install_package" and "aws_lambda_layer_version" "layer_google_cloud_bigquery"
Edit:
Compared two consecutive tfstate files, the hashes are same.


Is there any particular reason why you're using always_update = timestamp()? this means that always_update value will change every time you run terraform plan or apply changes, and consequently recreate the null_resource.

null_resource skips execution if we change the python package name/version. that's why I included timestamp to execute always. Not sure if there is a better way to do it.

The source_code_hash is pointing at the zip file. You are always rebuilding and re-zipping the files each time you apply, so the zip file's hash is definitely changing each time.

the hashes are same for two consecutive runs. updated the question with screenshot.

I tried to provide a sample demo code to show you how can you use zip file for lambda layer with source code hash. At the time of running terraform plan it will check the hash of the zip file and only deploy the layer if that hash has been changed.
In this way, lambda layer will only be created with a new version if there are any code changes in the src/lambda-layer. If there are no code changes then it will not create a new layer version.
data "archive_file" "layer_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "lambda-layer.zip"
  source_dir  = "../src/lambda-layer"
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "main" {
  layer_name          = "example-lambda-layer"
  filename            = "lambda-layer.zip"
  description         = "This is an example layer."
  compatible_runtimes = "nodejs20.x"
  license_info        = "MIT"
  source_code_hash    = data.archive_file.layer_zip.output_base64sha256
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
  function_name = "example-lambda-function"
  layers        = [aws_lambda_layer_version.main.arn]
  ...
}

